# Swift - toggle model to readonly momentarily

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, immutability

I have a phone number model which looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

struct PhoneValidation : OptionSet {
    let rawValue: Int
    
    static let phoneInValid = PhoneValidation(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let phoneValid = PhoneValidation(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let smsValidationAttempted = PhoneValidation(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let smsValidationFailed = PhoneValidation(rawValue: 1 << 3)
    static let smsValidationSuccessful = PhoneValidation(rawValue: 1 << 4)      // OTP is successfully validated in backend. The field should be non-editable in this duration
    static let smsValidationOTPTriggered = PhoneValidation(rawValue: 1 << 5)    // OTP validation triggered. The field should be non-editable in this duration
}

class PhonesViewModel: NSCopying {

    public var phoneType: PhoneNumberType = PhoneNumberType.mobile
    
    public var phone: String?
    
    public var code: String?
    
    public var countryCode: String?
    
    public var isValid : PhoneValidation?
    
    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        let copy = PhonesViewModel()
        copy.phoneType = phoneType
        copy.phone = phone
        copy.code = code
        copy.countryCode = countryCode
        copy.isValid = isValid
        return copy
    }
}
```

As you can see above the phone model can transition between different states. The SMS validation is available for few countries and for few it is not applicable. So, I plan on setting `smsValidationOTPTriggered` state when SMS validation is applicable for a country and while the validation is in progress.

What I need here is, while the states `smsValidationOTPTriggered` or `smsValidationSuccessful` are set I would not want any module of the application to modify the values(phoneType, phone, code, countryCode) of the model. In other words, I would like the model to switch to a read-only mode while these 2 states are set in model and would like the module to be informed with an error or exception when a modification is attempted.

Is there a best practice already available for what I am trying to achieve here? I have searched before raising this question but did not find any. How can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Raj Pawan Gumdal

Comment: Why not start with an immutable version of your class? Just like string and mutable string, array and mutable array, and so on. So no one can keep a mutable reference to your model.

Comment: Also you should not be allowing direct access to the model properties anyway. All properties should be private with accessors. So the accessors can just lock the doors.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this, I think its better to use property wrappers for your case! The below is not an exact solution but can modify/change to accommodate your need
import UIKit

```
 enum PhoneNumberType {
    case mobile
}

enum PhoneValidation {
    case phoneInValid
    case phoneValid
    case smsValidationAttempted
    case smsValidationFailed
    case smsValidationSuccessful
    case smsValidationOTPTriggered
}

struct PhonesViewModel {
    public var phoneType: PhoneNumberType = PhoneNumberType.mobile
    public var phone: String?
    public var code: String?
    public var countryCode: String?
    public var phoneValidation : PhoneValidation?
    
    func validate(value: [PhoneValidation]) -> Bool {
        //add proper check here
        return false 
    }
}


@propertyWrapper
struct Wrapper {
    private(set) var value: PhonesViewModel? = nil
    var validators: [PhoneValidation] = []
    
    var wrappedValue: PhonesViewModel? {
        get { value }
        set {
            if let model = newValue, model.validate(value: validators) {
                value = newValue
                print("Value assigned")
            } else {
                print("Value not assigned")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SomeOtherClass {
    @Wrapper(validators: [PhoneValidation.phoneInValid])
    var model: PhonesViewModel?
}

var a = SomeOtherClass()
a.model = PhonesViewModel()
a.model = PhonesViewModel()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I presume this solves the problem where `a.model` cannot be changed by any module, that's good. What I also need is no one should be able to do `a.model.phone = "SomeOtherNumber"` too. Meaning the inner property of object should also be readonly. How can I do that?

Comment: @RajPawanGumdal That's why I created struct instead of Class. is it ok for you to use a struct. So if you enforce struct it is not possible to modify the value, every time if someone wants to update the value he/she needs to create a new struct (since the validation is already there for the model this should work)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a technique with the name "popsicle immutability". An object is initially mutable, but can be "frozen". Modifications for frozen objects are forbidden. In your case `PhonesViewModel` become frozen when `isValid` property have value `smsValidationOTPTriggered` or `smsValidationSuccessful`.

Let's add `Freezable` protocol for requirements to objects that can become immutable and conforming for `PhonesViewModel`:

```swift
protocol Freezable: class {
    var isFrozen: Bool { get }
}

extension PhonesViewModel: Freezable {
    var isFrozen: Bool {
        isValid == .smsValidationOTPTriggered || isValid == .smsValidationSuccessful
    }
}
```

Now we must add validation for `isFrozen` value when a property is assigned. It can be added in property observers like:

```swift
...
public var phone: String? {
    didSet {
        validate()
    }
}
...
private func validate() {
    assert(!isFrozen)
}
```

Or using property wrapper:

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct Guarded<Value> {
    private var value: Value

    init(wrappedValue: Value) {
        value = wrappedValue
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { fatalError("only works on instance properties of classes that conforms to Freezable protocol") }
        set { fatalError("only works on instance properties of classes that conforms to Freezable protocol") }
    }

    static subscript<EnclosingSelf: Freezable>(
        _enclosingInstance object: EnclosingSelf,
        wrapped wrappedKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<EnclosingSelf, Value>,
        storage storageKeyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<EnclosingSelf, Self>
    ) -> Value {
        get {
            object[keyPath: storageKeyPath].value
        }
        set {
            precondition(!object.isFrozen, "Object \(object) is frozen! Modifications are forbidden")
            object[keyPath: storageKeyPath].value = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

So your class will look like:

```swift
class PhonesViewModel: NSCopying {

    @Guarded
    public var phoneType: PhoneNumberType = PhoneNumberType.mobile

    @Guarded
    public var phone: String?

    @Guarded
    public var code: String?

    @Guarded
    public var countryCode: String?

    @Guarded
    public var isValid : PhoneValidation?

    func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        let copy = PhonesViewModel()
        copy.phoneType = phoneType
        copy.phone = phone
        copy.code = code
        copy.countryCode = countryCode
        copy.isValid = isValid
        return copy
    }
}
```